# Find the value of a 5th-root expression.

Tags: radicals

Simplify and find the value of the expression:

$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}{2}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}{2}}.$$

I tried to rationalise it.

It was of no use..

Comment: Note that $ab=1$ and $a^5+b^5=123$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}{2}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}{2}}=x$$

Raise to the power of 5 on both sides,
$$(\sqrt[5]{\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}{2}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}{2}})^5=x^5$$

Use the identity:
$$(a+b)^5=a^5+b^5+5ab[(a+b)^3-ab(a+b)]$$
We know that $(a+b)=x$.

Simlifying $a×b$ that is 
$\sqrt[5]{\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}{2}}×\sqrt[5]{\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}{2}},$ we get $1$.

By substituting, the expression simplifies to the polynomial $$x^5=123+5[x^3-x]$$
$$x^5-5x^3+5x-123=0$$
Solving the degree 5 polynomial, we get
$$x=3$$..$Ans..$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}2=\frac{123+55\sqrt5}2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\right)^5.$$
Likewise
$$\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}2=\left(\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\right)^5.$$
So 
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}2}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{123-\sqrt{15125}}2}
=\frac{3+\sqrt5}2+\frac{3-\sqrt5}2=3.$$

Comment: Is there any way other than expanding the R.H.S. to verify that $$\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{10}?$$

Comment: @MathLover The LHS is a unit in the algebraic integers of $Q(\sqrt5)$ and so a power of the fundamental unit.

Comment: How is $$\frac{123+\sqrt{15125}}2=\frac{123+55\sqrt5}2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\right)^5?$$

Comment: @RyanScott Which of those equalities are you having difficulty with?

Comment: $$\frac{123+55\sqrt5}2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\right)^5.$$This one..

Comment: Which of those two equalities are you having difficulty with? @RyanScott

Comment: I have a difficulty with both the equalities.Please help

Comment: For a start $((1+\sqrt5)/2)^2=(1+2\sqrt5+5)/4=(3+\sqrt5)/2$.